# Using another site to secure my site

Tags: .net, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to write a website that will add additional functionality beyond what an existing site offers.

But I would rather not setup my own security for my site.

I am thinking I will write some web api services that I want to be secure.

This is what the existing site says about its login page:

> This is the URL you will use to authenticate the user. If the authentication was successful, you should get a 200 response code and the phrase "Sign In" shouldn't be found in the response body. Use an HTTP POST for this request.

I know that I could call the login page for every service call, but I want the user to have to login only once.

Is there some way I can know they logged in recently but still protect against someone who is trying to spoof that they have logged in?

Comment: I'm afraid it is truly difficult to understand what are your requirements. Do you own the existing site and/or can you modify it? What authentication mechanism is using this existing site (cookies, bearer token, etc.)? Looking at your question as is I believe you have no option to reuse existing authentication.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - I do not own the existing site.  I am hoping to use its authentication similar to an Open Id provider (though they don't implement Open Id).  I was hoping for something like, "Use API `something` and it will generate a secure token that you can put in a cookie and know that it is legit" or something like that.  I just don't know much about web security, so I am asking here.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to implement OAuth.

Comment: If this existing site do not provides a standard API for Authentication/Authorization (OpenId, OAuth, etc.) then you have no chance to use it as an authentication provider. I may assume that it simply use some kind of cookie to persist authentication state. This is like a black box for you, and you cannot find out if a user is authenticated.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - So, just thinking about this, if I send the user to the login page, and get back a 200 code, then I generate a fairly long token that is stored on the client and the server, then I add that token to each call using HTTPS (and eventually time out the token)... would that not work?  (If the token does not match then they are not authenticated and I redirect to the login page.)

Comment: While this could be feasible from a high level approach, you are tightly coupling your Authentication logic to an API that (from what I can see looking at the only spec you provided) is not designed to support such use case. I'm not saying it will not work, but I definitely do not advice you to do it (security is always a touchy subject).

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 2 options to to do that via Single Sign On.

1. Using Federated Authentication using Ws-Federation.
2. Using oAUTH 2.0/Open-Id connect using something like IdentityServer.

Comment: If I send the user to the login page, and get back a 200 code, then I generate a fairly long token that is stored on the client and the server, then I add that token to each call using HTTPS (and eventually time out the token)... would that not work?  (If the token does not match then they are not authenticated and I redirect to the login page.)

Comment: instead of re-inventing the wheel, please read up on the options the mentioned below https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498017.aspx Code Samples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545413(v=vs.110).aspx and https://github.com/IdentityServer

Comment: I thought that I would need to have their site support this too...  Can it be done on just my side?

Comment: Please look at some examples of Owin based security. If the external site is supporting Open Id specification, you can use external login providers like Google/Facebook, alternatively you can also configure and use your own company's Identity provider or configure an Instance of Identity Server to do that. Here is a link below which shows an example of Owin Security with External Providers : http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana